# Using && Operators with Boolean and Integers . error! && can not be used with Boolean and Integers

Tags: android

```
if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
               if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

Comment: `... && grantResults[0]=PackageManager...` don't you miss a **=**?

Answer (score 0):

you have used one equals sign to get the equality of two variables which is invalid, you should use two equals sign to get the equality of two variables not one equals sign, so try to change :-

> Old

```
if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] /*there ->*/ = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
        Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
}
```

> New

```
if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
        Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mohib if it's working you can use vote the answer as working answer instead of thanking.